# Android HttpClient performance

Tags: android, performance, httpclient

I developing android app which uses a lot of http requests to web service. At first, I was creating a new HttpClient instance before every request.
To increase performance I try to do requests in many threads. So, I created single HttpClient instance, shared by all threads, using ThreadSafeConnectionManager:

```
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 100);
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

ThreadSafeClientConnManager connManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager, params);
```

But performance decreased, to my surprise. I have measured time, to be spended to exequte requests in such way:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);
long reqTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
Log.i("SyncTimer", "Request time:" + reqTime);
```

Here this is a log, which I get with simple DefaultHttpClient without parameters new instance per request:

```
01-11 11:10:51.136: INFO/SyncTimer(18400): Request time:1076
01-11 11:10:54.686: INFO/SyncTimer(18400): Request time:1051
01-11 11:10:57.996: INFO/SyncTimer(18400): Request time:1054
01-11 11:10:59.166: INFO/SyncTimer(18400): Request time:1070
01-11 11:11:00.346: INFO/SyncTimer(18400): Request time:1172
01-11 11:11:02.656: INFO/SyncTimer(18400): Request time:1043
```

And what I get with ThreadSafeClientConnManager and single HttpClient instance:

```
01-11 11:06:06.926: INFO/SyncTimer(18267): Request time:7001
01-11 11:06:10.412: INFO/SyncTimer(18267): Request time:3385
01-11 11:06:20.222: INFO/SyncTimer(18267): Request time:9801
01-11 11:06:23.622: INFO/SyncTimer(18267): Request time:2058
01-11 11:06:29.906: INFO/SyncTimer(18267): Request time:6268
01-11 11:06:34.746: INFO/SyncTimer(18267): Request time:3525
01-11 11:06:50.302: INFO/SyncTimer(18267): Request time:15551
```

What happens and how can I fight this?

**UPDATE**

Use keep-alive advantage - is what I want. But when I create new HttpClient instance for every request connection can not be reused. Despite of this, such version runs faster, reasons of it is unclear for me.

Comment: All I can say is that Parallel with Synchronization is slower than Serial without Synchronization. Hence why Parallel ports died and Serial USB ports won.

Comment: Are all the requests to the same web-service/host?  It could be the server that doesn't like it, or you might be losing your HTTP 'keepalive' advantage by doing 10 units of work on a 100 threads.  Are the requests large? Bandwidth could be a bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, requests are to the same web-service. Number of threads is less then number of requests, in fact I test it with 2 or 3 threads. Requests are small, just few xml tags.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is all very simple. HttpClient per default allows only two concurrent connections to the same target host as required by the HTTP specification. So, effectively your worker threads spend most of their execution time blocked waiting for those two connections to become available.

You should increase the 'max connections per route' limit to reduce / eliminate worker thread contention.

You might also want to check out the benchmark used by Apache HttpComponents project to measure performance of HttpClient.

http://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/HttpClient3vsHttpClient4vsHttpCore

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the context switching is resulting in poor performance with the thread safe manager, and you should stop using it. I suppose you could compare the Apache client with the default Java client, but I don't think you are going to get much of a performance gain.

Personally, I've found the DOM XML parser to be a bit slow, so if you are using XML reformatiing it may help. Depending on your app you may be able to request items before you need them or use caching to create a better user expierence, but we would need to know more to give you meaningful advice.