# Android DefaultHttpClient REST api

Tags: android, apache

I implemented a small android application which received data from a server via REST api. Every Activity contains an AsyncTask which is get the requested data from the server. I use DefaultHttpClient with ThreadSafeConnManager, and the client is a singleton in order to reuse it. 
When I test the app and I walking through the activities, there is a strange problem: everything's working a while and suddenly receiving the data takes longer and longer time. It happens if I hit back button in an activity fast - I suspect because of the asynctask the client connection hasn't released and the new task can't connect. But the same happens if I create a new client instance every HttpGet.

I stuck with this problem and no clue what's wrong. Any help appreciated.

Thanks, and br Peter

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks get kind of tricky, especially with long running operations.
Sounds like you possibly have several tasks attempting to fill your requests. Remember that at some time in the process your client WILL block.

I suggest you move away from asyncTasks and to a threaded service with a request queue.
If you decide to continue with asyncTasks, make sure that your cancels are properly implemented.

hope this helps

Comment: Hi! I tried to cancel the requests. (Not all activity) Where should I put the cancel methods? In onPause and onDestroy methods? The cancel method will release the connection? THanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been discussed:

[Android HttpClient performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654480/android-httpclient-perfomance)

1. turn on debug level logging for the connectionMgr, inspect lifecycle events
2. look at  closeExpiredConnections() method look at
3. closeIdleConnections(long idleTimeout, TimeUnit tunit)

I think you should look a little closer at the lifecycle of the connections from your connectionPool and in particular, are idle and unused connections being closed and or reused.

You can look at the API/ Docs for the ThreadSafeConnManager or you can look at the source.

Comment: I tried but didn't worked well. Each of every run I get infinite progress bar after a few click.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper approach for your case, within the same page of what Nelson suggests.

I'd try to take more control over my requests and thread executors. Remember that Asynctask's pool is limited. If your operations are long enough, the request will be enqueued larger.

http://joseluisugia.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/using-runnables-queues-and-executors-to-perform-tasks-in-background-threads-in-android/