# Android HttpURLConnection, HttpClient coexistence and connections limits

Tags: android, http

I have taken over maintaining an Android app that has been built to use both HttpURLConnection and HttpClient from threads. A new instance is used each time, rather than reusing a shared instance (I know that this is not good practice, at least for HttpClient, and I intend to change it). Most of the connections are made to the same server; I find that when some connections are busy, other threads are blocked.
I understand from [Android HttpClient performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654480/android-httpclient-perfomance) that  HttpClient per default allows only two concurrent connections to the same target host.
I also see from the answer in [URLConnection or HTTPClient : Which offers better functionality and more efficiency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551058/urlconnection-or-httpclient-which-offers-better-functionality-and-more-efficie) that with HttpUrlConnection concurrent connections to the same host get serialized.

How do I change the concurrent connections limit for HttpClient and HttpUrlConnection?
Can HttpURLConnection and HttpClient coexist in the same app without problems, or would it be better to use just one of them?
Thanks.

Comment: What did you decide on doing, Damien?

Answer (score 3):

Google has stated that HttpClient is no longer being maintained in Android, which basically means, that it may stick around, but they are not going to enhance it.  They prefer that people use HttpUrlConnection, HttpUrlConnection has some bugs depending on the version of Androind :(  (you can read more about both choices on the Android Developer Blog http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Personally, I'd take a look at OkHttp (by Square) since it provides an almost drop in replacement for HttpUrlConnection but it offers connection pooling and SPDY support.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: Thank you. I looked at OkHttp and I cannot yet determine if it also applies a limit on concurrent connections to the same host. I am continuing to test the app under various connection loads.

Comment: I switched from HttpClient to OkHttpClient and no longer get the I/O exception: java.io.EOFException:    at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
 (Jelly Bean). Thanks!